# Do gym badges have any piracy protection?

Tags: pokemon

Between the games, anime, and manga, there appear to at least be *over one hundred* unique gym badges across all the regions, most, if not all, of which grant the holder some special ability or access to other areas. It is also implied that the badges can be used as a gym leader's identification, an example being when Brock used his Boulder Badge to prove he wasn't involved in a crime.

Given the power the badges possess, it doesn't seem far-fetched that there would be people forging them, either to break into the higher leagues, to steal someone's identity, or even simply to show off (looking at you, [Gary](https://goo.gl/images/d87EXw)).

**Has this ever been an issue? Is there any special trait of gym badges that allows people to tell them apart from fake ones?**

Comment: We certainly know that they can be stolen; https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gym_Badge_thieves and presumably the level of craftmanship invoved in their creation would act as a deterrent to fraud.

Answer (score 5):

Tying into a past question about [getting paid after a battle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189155/how-do-pokemon-trainers-collect-their-winnings), I suspect that in addition to the physical badge, there's an entry in a database that records the accomplishment, all controlled through Bill's computer network, and accessible via the Pokedex or other device.

There's actually a real-world precedent - [**Blue Peter badges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Peter_badge). 
[image]

Blue Peter is a decades-long-running children's show in the UK. People who appear as guests on the show, celebrities, or members of the viewing audience who do things of note (like winning a competition, or doing some public work that gets them recognition) are awarded the Blue Peter Badge, with colors (and ranks of honor) from blue to gold. The badges actually afford some benefits, such as discounts at national museums, but the real prestige is in owning one.

They started coming up for sale on eBay, and there was quite a kerfuffle about it.  A young girl suggested that the badge have added security, including a photo ID card, so it couldn't be transferred or sold. She was awarded a Silver Badge for her idea.

So while you could lay your hands on a badge if you wanted to, it's useless without the documentation to back it up.